# Using `issubclass()` with Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some Django models, say

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Bar(Foo)
    pass
```

I would like to be able to find all models inheriting from Foo, in order to perform a task with them. It should be easy, like

```
from django.db import models
from myapp.models import Foo

for model in models.get_models():
    if issubclass(model, Foo):
        do_something()
```

Alas, this does not work, since `issubclass(Bar, Foo)` reports `False`, probably as a result of the inner working of the Django metaclass that initializes the models.

> Is there a way to check whether a Django models is a descendant of an abstract Django model?

Please, do not suggest duck typing as the solution. In this case, I really would like to know whether a subclass relation exists.

Comment: Asking myself the same question...
After many tests and code introspection, I guess it doesn't seem to be possible, as abstract models are callables, and son objects haven't got any attributes or methods which fits this needs.

Comment: Seems weird... I just created a new django app in a virtualenv, and your code is working, my 'do_something()' is simply a 'print model' and it works. result : <class 'app.models.Bar'>.
Are you sure your problem comes from abstract ?
FYI I'm using django 1.3.1

Comment: Also working for me on Django 1.3.1

Comment: I have to admint, on a fresh project it works for me too. The problem must lie somewhere else. Sorry, and thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you import the classes. Instead of:

```
from myapp.models import Foo
```

use:

```
from myproject.myapp.models import Foo
```

To see what is the right way, you can see how Django is importing your models with:

```
print models.get_models()
```

Comment: can you explain why there's a problem if i import using `myapp.models`? 
Then if i wanna write a reusable app, i have to write import-things without project name, or i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
subclasses = Foo.__subclasses__()
for subclass in subclasses:
    # we need to keep looking for subclasses of the subclasses
    subclasses += subclass.__subclasses__()
# sometimes we don't care about abstract classes
concrete_subclasses = filter(lambda c: not c._meta.abstract, subclasses)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Bar._meta.get_base_chain(Foo)
```

to get a list describing the inheritance chain between `Foo` and `Bar`.